# Sci fi movie that starts with a missing child and ends with reality slowly breaking down

Tags: story-identification, movie, hard-sci-fi, alien-invasion

I'm trying to remember the name of this sci fi movie. I'm pretty sure it's at least 2000's movie, not earlier. What I remember of the plot is, a married couple goes out on a date. 2 siblings stay home. When they get back, the younger sibling is missing. They end up blaming the either the other sibling or the grandfather for the disappearance. The family goes out into the woods to look for the child and they encounter something strange, like aliens or strange lights. They come back to the house and then the house gets attacked. There are strange lights and sounds. Reality slowly starts to break down and what happened to the child is shown to the mother. Ending is kinda sad. Anyone know the title of this movie?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you actually watch this?

Comment: Possibly in 2015. It's not a newer movie. I would say it's between 2010 and 2015.

Comment: Okay. Your description reminds me very much of [_Dark Encounter_ (2019)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Encounter), but I guess that's too recent.

Comment: How that house was attacked? What happened in the end?

Comment: Yes, it is Dark Encounter!! Just found the trailer on Tubi. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Please consider marking [my answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/275927/122024) below as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

Answer (score 3):

This is ***[Dark Encounter](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8269120/)*** (2019).

> Eight-year-old Maisie went missing in 1982 and a memorial is held by her family a year later. That evening, strange lights and sounds are observed in the woods outside - and strange things start to happen.

The film begins with a husband and wife returning home after a trip into town to find their young daughter missing. The film then skips a year ahead in time, and the husband and wife are having various relatives over to dinner. The daughter is still missing, her disappearance unexplained, and the couple has one son remaining.

Subsequently, the family experiences various paranormal phenomena, including visions and mysterious lights in the woods. They begin to wonder if their daughter was kidnapped by aliens.

In the end... (major spoilers)

> ... it's revealed that an uncle murdered the daughter and buried her in the woods, and that an alien was attempting to communicate with the family (by showing them visions) to let them know what really happened.